# Not able to produce message in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

As soon as i try to produce message in my multinode multibroker kafka cluster, i get the following error and not able to produce message. I am able to list and describe topics properly.

```
 bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic nil_RF2_P1

[2016-06-17 06:55:08,555] WARN Property topic is not valid (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
hi
[2016-06-17 06:55:10,844] WARN Fetching topic metadata with correlation id 0 for topics [Set(nil_RF2_P1)] from broker [id:0,host:localhost,port:9092] failed (kafka.client.ClientUtils$)
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:100)
at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.liftedTree1$1(SyncProducer.scala:73)
at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.kafka$producer$SyncProducer$$doSend(SyncProducer.scala:72)
at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.send(SyncProducer.scala:113)
at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:58)
at kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo.updateInfo(BrokerPartitionInfo.scala:82)
at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler$$anonfun$handle$1.apply$mcV$sp(DefaultEventHandler.scala:67)
at kafka.utils.Utils$.swallow(Utils.scala:172)
at kafka.utils.Logging$class.swallowError(Logging.scala:106)
at kafka.utils.Utils$.swallowError(Utils.scala:45)
at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.handle(DefaultEventHandler.scala:67)
at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.tryToHandle(ProducerSendThread.scala:105)
at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread$$anonfun$processEvents$3.apply(ProducerSendThread.scala:88)
at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread$$anonfun$processEvents$3.apply(ProducerSendThread.scala:68)
at scala.collection.immutable.Stream.foreach(Stream.scala:594)
at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.processEvents(ProducerSendThread.scala:67)
at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.run(ProducerSendThread.scala:45)
[2016-06-17 06:55:10,847] ERROR fetching topic metadata for topics [Set(nil_RF2_P1)] from broker [ArrayBuffer(id:0,host:localhost,port:9092)] failed (kafka.utils.Utils$)
kafka.common.KafkaException: fetching topic metadata for topics [Set(nil_RF2_P1)] from broker [ArrayBuffer(id:0,host:localhost,port:9092)] failed
at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:72)
at kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo.updateInfo(BrokerPartitionInfo.scala:82)
at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler$$anonfun$handle$1.apply$mcV$sp(DefaultEventHandler.scala:67)
at kafka.utils.Utils$.swallow(Utils.scala:172)
at kafka.utils.Logging$class.swallowError(Logging.scala:106)
at kafka.utils.Utils$.swallowError(Utils.scala:45)
at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.handle(DefaultEventHandler.scala:67)
at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.tryToHandle(ProducerSendThread.scala:105)
at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread$$anonfun$processEvents$3.apply(ProducerSendThread.scala:88)
at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread$$anonfun$processEvents$3.apply(ProducerSendThread.scala:68)
at scala.collection.immutable.Stream.foreach(Stream.scala:594)
at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.processEvents(ProducerSendThread.scala:67)
at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.run(ProducerSendThread.scala:45)
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:100)
at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.liftedTree1$1(SyncProducer.scala:73)
at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.kafka$producer$SyncProducer$$doSend(SyncProducer.scala:72)
at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.send(SyncProducer.scala:113)
at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:58)
... 12 more

[2016-06-17 06:55:10,851] WARN Fetching topic metadata with correlation id 1 for topics [Set(nil_RF2_P1)] from broker [id:0,host:localhost,port:9092] failed (kafka.client.ClientUtils$)
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:100)
at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.liftedTree1$1(SyncProducer.scala:73)
at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.kafka$producer$SyncProducer$$doSend(SyncProducer.scala:72)
at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.send(SyncProducer.scala:113)
at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:58)
at kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo.updateInfo(BrokerPartitionInfo.scala:82)
at kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo.getBrokerPartitionInfo(BrokerPartitionInfo.scala:49)
at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.kafka$producer$async$DefaultEventHandler$$getPartitionListForTopic(DefaultEventHandler.scala:186)
at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler$$anonfun$partitionAndCollate$1.apply(DefaultEventHandler.scala:150)
at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler$$anonfun$partitionAndCollate$1.apply(DefaultEventHandler.scala:149)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.partitionAndCollate(DefaultEventHandler.scala:149)
at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.dispatchSerializedData(DefaultEventHandler.scala:95)
at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.handle(DefaultEventHandler.scala:72)
at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.tryToHandle(ProducerSendThread.scala:105)
at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread$$anonfun$processEvents$3.apply(ProducerSendThread.scala:88)
at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread$$anonfun$processEvents$3.apply(ProducerSendThread.scala:68)
at scala.collection.immutable.Stream.foreach(Stream.scala:594)
at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.processEvents(ProducerSendThread.scala:67)
at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.run(ProducerSendThread.scala:45)
```

Has someone faced a similar issue??

Regards

Comment: can you confirm if kafka if up and running?

Comment: yes it is running..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Got the solution to it.

I had to change the producer.properties file for my multi node multi broker kafka cluster , with the following  :

```
metadata.broker.list=2:172.16.30.4:9092,4:172.16.30.4:9093,1:172.16.30.5:9092,3:172.16.30.5:9093

Explanation:
We have 2 nodes
172.16.30.4
172.16.30.5

with 2 brokers running in ports 
9092
9093

The preceeding integer in each ip is the myid of the zookeeper, while successing integer is port!!
```

Hope it would help some one.